# changing state error on component will unmount

Tags: react-native

I have a class component which user may use to c change language of the App , I have added this screen to create Stack navigator , my issue is when I navigate to it , the console displays Error saying :

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
>   This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
>   To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the
>   componentWillUnmount method.

I am not seeing that I am calling  component will unmount , could you please help here is my code :

```
 class Languages extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          loc : null
        };
      }

      onChangeLan(lanz) {
        this.setState({ loc : lanz})
       this.props.languaje(lanz.locale)   
      }

      render() {
        return (
              <View style = { styles.contianer}>
              {
                Langua.map( (lan) =>{
                  return (

                  <ListItem 
                  key = {lan.id}
                  title= {lan.name}
                  onPress = { this.onChangeLan.bind(this,lan)}
                  />

                  )
                })

              }

                <Text>{I18n.t('login')}</Text>

               </View>
        );
      }
    }
    const mapStateToProps = state =>{
      return {
       language : state.lan.locale
      }
    }
    export default connect(mapStateToProps,{languaje})(Languages);

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      contianer : {
        flex: 1
      }   
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

That error indicates that you're attempting to use `setState` on a component that has unmounted. The error is trying to help you by indicating that any asynchronous action that could potentially result in a `setState` should be cancelled when the component unmounts, not that you have an error in your `componentWillUnmount` method. Take a look at the stack trace and find where the error is originating from.